# get HTML of dynamically created table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been asked numerous times but never really answered specifically without the use of a third party application.

I have dynamically created rows in a table that already has 2 static rows. The rows are created fine and appended to the `:last` and I can get/pull/push the `.val` `.text` ect... but cannot get the full html output as seen in 'view page source' of most browsers.

Even examples like: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;` don't retrieve the dynamically created rows.

Only the static table will show even with `console.log($(this).html());` in the `.each`

Would like the html returned to include the values from `<textarea>` and `<span>`

```
 $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'invoice_fill.php',                         
        data: {action: "invoice" },                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            var result = [];
            var invoices; 

            $.each(data, function(i, e) {

            invoices = this;
            $(".item-row:last").after(
              '<tr class="item-row">'+
              '<td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc['+i+']">Description</textarea></td>'+
              '<td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost['+i+']">$0</textarea></td>'+
              '<td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty['+i+']">0</textarea></td>'+
              '<td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price['+i+']">$0</span></td></tr>');

            $('[name="item_desc['+i+']"]').val(invoices.description);
            $('[name="item_cost['+i+']"]').val(invoices.cost);
            $('[name="item_qty['+i+']"]').val(invoices.quantity);
            $('[name="item_price['+i+']"]').val(invoices.price);

            console.log($(this).html());
            console.log($('.item-row').html());

      });

        }
});

<table id="items">

      <tr>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$150.00</span></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
          <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
          <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
          </div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$95.00</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$95.00</span></td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `this` refers to the object passed in `data` argument, not to any DOM element. Do you need the HTML of the newly-created row or of the entire table?

Comment: either will due, as long as it includes the dynamic rows

Comment: In the loop, `$(".item-row:last").html()` should return the HTML of the newly-created row.

Comment: ok I see where I'm asking wrong: would like the html output to include the values or text from the `textarea` and `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took for while to understand what you need. `value` of `textarea` is not reflected to its `innerHTML`. Set also HTML, like `$('[name="item_desc[' + i + ']"]').val(...).html(...)` (et al) additionally to `.val()`, that way you can see the values in HTML of the row too.

See a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b3yLgne/1/).

Comment: I think thats the problem I'm having, I'm getting the `.val` but its not in the`.html` when the page loads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992056/calculate-product-price-on-ajax-call

Comment: @BarclayVision Yes, like I said in my answer, value is not reflected to innerHTML, you have to set both.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the whole HTML table source by simply calling:

```
console.log( $("#items").html() );
```

I see that you have some code `console.log($('.item-row').html());` but that has no point because that will output only first `.item-row`.

Comment: as I stated in my question - `console.log( $("#items").html() );` only returns the static row of the html, and not the dynamic row.

Comment: sorry, I updated question, I was not clear in my question!

Comment: @BarclayVision can you provide me exact output you are expecting so we can give you right answer

Comment: full html of table with values including dynamically created rows. need to see textarea and span with html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this pure javascript code

```
document.getElementById("tableid").outerHTML;
```

Comment: i get null error with `console.log(document.getElementById("#items").outerHTML);`

Comment: remove the # from inside of the braces

Comment: Try this `console.log(document.getElementById("items").outerHTML);`

Comment: that still only returns the static rows

Comment: Strange. because this is directly from DOM. Are you sure you are adding the rows to this table. check for silly mistakes.

Comment: see; https://jsfiddle.net/ujaet94z/45 I'm not getting price results in dynamic and not able to show html with values

Comment: take a look at this example i created for you. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1TE2ZIQ5I7V

Comment: I'm not getting the same results - take a look at my example above

Comment: your fiddle is just too much code, but as per documentation outerHTML will give you actual rendered html of the element from the DOM.

Comment: ok i'll work with that... I have another problem I'm trying to solve from that fiddle and the html would help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992056/calculate-product-price-on-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is use of `console.log($(this).html());`. The `this` inside loop is ajax result object.

I created a sample `html`. Please see complete code and points to be noted.

- You uses `console.log($(this).html());` inside loop but its wrong.
  Because `this` inside loop is the `json` object.
- Why you using
  `$('[name="item_desc['+i+']"]').val(invoices.description);` Instead
  you can set it like `<textarea form ="testinsert"
  name="item_desc[]">' + invoices.description + '</textarea>`
- Ajax is now loading inside document ready.
- The `console.log($('#items').html());` printed outside of loop.

Hope this will help.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="items">

    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name">
            <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
                <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
                <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="description"><textarea form="testinsert"
                                          name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="cost" form="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty" form="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price" form="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$150.00</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item-row">
        <td class="item-name">
            <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
                <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
                <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">A</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="description"><textarea form="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea>
        </td>
        <td><textarea class="cost" form="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$95.00</textarea></td>
        <td><textarea class="qty" form="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">1</textarea></td>
        <td><span class="price" form="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$95.00</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $.ajax({
            url: 'invoice_fill.php',
            data: {action: "invoice"},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var result = [];
                var invoices;

                $.each(data, function (i, e) {

                    invoices = this;
                    $(".item-row:last").after(
                        '<tr class="item-row">' +
                        '<td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">' + invoices.description + '</textarea></td>' +
                        '<td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">' + invoices.cost + '</textarea></td>' +
                        '<td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">' + invoices.quantity + '</textarea></td>' +
                        '<td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">' + invoices.price + '</span></td></tr>');
                                    });
                //console.log($(this).html());
                // console.log($('.item-row').html());
                console.log($('#items').html());

            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```