# I am trying to create a table of 8x8 squares in HTML using script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I thought maybe doing this with a for loop like that

```html
<table>
  <script>
    for (var i; i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      document.write("<tr>")
      for (var j; j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        document.write("<td></td>")
      }
      document.write("<tr>")
    }
  </script>
</table>
```

This code doesn't seem to work. Please understand that I am not at all fluent in js, so a solution with an explenationn will really help.

Comment: Instead of `document.write`, create htmlString and set it to cody

Comment: In a `for` loop you can have 2 semicolons. Here you have 3: `for (var i; i = 0; i < 8; i++)`. It should be `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)`. You could also use a comma operator, which however would make little sense: `for (var i, i = 0; i < 8; i++)`.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. **Read the error messages**. Typo: There are three components to a `for(...)`, not four. Your initializer should be **one** statement, not two: `var i; i = 0;` should be `var i = 0;`. (and ditto for `j`)

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: accept/upvote answer if it helped, check [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get HTML of dynamically created table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023299/get-html-of-dynamically-created-table-rows)

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` would not work as you have tried here, it won't write the `<tr>` tags at the place you've mentioned either.

You need to modify the DOM, specifically the `table` element.

Below code, takes a reference of `table` and appends the 8 rows and 8 cols in it.

```js
document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = new Array(8).fill("<tr>" + new Array(8).fill("<td></td>").join("") + "</tr>").join("");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

PS: This is a basic example to get you started, there are better ways to achieve this. you should look more into DOM Manipulation in JS.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write()` will never create a child element inside the `<table>` element, you can create a child element for a parent with `appendChild()`.

Here an example with pure JavaScript:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  document.getElementById('tbl').appendChild(row).setAttribute("id", 'row_' + i);
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var column = document.createElement("td");
    document.getElementById('row_' + i).appendChild(column);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl'></table>
```

Here, the script will create a child `<tr>` for the `<table>`, then you can create child `<td>` for the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM manipulation methods and make sure to put `<script>` right before the closing tag of `<body>` instead of inside `<tabl>` , here is a working example:

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table');
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  let row = document.createElement('TR');
  table.appendChild(row);

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var cell = document.createElement('TD');
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```